# How can I extract the string value fro StringPath value in querydsl?

Tags: querydsl

I tried running this code.

```
List<TbFrLanguageInfo> list = queryFactory.selectFrom(qTbFrLanguageInfo)
        .where( qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq
                .eq(   (String) (( map.get("languageSq") ==null || map.get("languageSq").equals("") ) ? qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq.stringValue() :map.get("languageSq"))     ) 
                .and( qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageId
                        .eq( (String) ((map.get("languageId") == null  || map.get("languageId").equals("") ) ?  qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageId.stringValue() : map.get("languageId"))) )
                .and ( qTbFrLanguageInfo.useYn.eq( (String) (( map.get("useYn")== null || map.get("useYn").equals("")) ?  qTbFrLanguageInfo.useYn.stringValue() : map.get("useYn"))   ))
                ).orderBy(qTbFrLanguageInfo.orderNo.asc()).fetch();
```

But I got error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.StringPath cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.module.language.dao.impl.LanguageMgnDaoImpl.selectLanguageList(LanguageMgnDaoImpl.java:72)
    at com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.module.language.dao.impl.LanguageMgnDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d2a565a4.invoke(<generated>)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried it.

```
List<TbFrLanguageInfo> list = queryFactory
        .selectFrom(qTbFrLanguageInfo)
        .where(  
                qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq.eq(
                        ( map.get("languageSq") ==null || map.get("languageSq").equals("") ) ?  
                                qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq : Expressions.constant( map.get("languageSq")))      
                .and( qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageId.eq(  
                        ((map.get("languageId") == null  || map.get("languageId").equals("") ) ?  
                                qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageId : Expressions.constant(map.get("languageId"))) ))
                .and ( qTbFrLanguageInfo.useYn.eq( 
                        ( map.get("useYn")== null || map.get("useYn").equals("")) ?  
                                qTbFrLanguageInfo.useYn : Expressions.constant( map.get("useYn")))   )
                ).orderBy(qTbFrLanguageInfo.orderNo.asc()).fetch();
```

The error is like the followings. I think there is easy way to solve this...

```
The method eq(String) in the type SimpleExpression<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<capture#1-of ? extends Object>)
```

The weird thing is that it is working if I remove the ? : operator and use one  expression like the below.

```
qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq.eq(qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq)
qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq.eq( Expressions.constant( map.get("languageSq")) )
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the cast to `String` and using `Expressions.constant` to wrap the `String` values, E.G. `Expressions.constant(map.get("languageId"))`?

Comment: @RobertBain Sorry for late. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: The method eq(String) in the type SimpleExpression<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<capture#2-of ? extends Object>)

Comment: Have you tried to save the result to your `? :` expression to a variable, i.e. `Expression<String> ex = map.get("languageSq") ==null || map.get("languageSq").equals("") ? qTbFrLanguageInfo.languageSq : Expressions.constant( map.get("languageSq"));`?